# How to get bytestring from onActivityResult?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I would like to get smth like this:

```
...2 47 ef bf bd cb 92 3a 53 0e 5e ef bf bd ef bf bd d6...
```

As I understood it is string content of file which is converted to bytes. I tried such way:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, result: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, result)
        when {
            requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                if (result != null) {
                    val documentFile: DocumentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, result.data!!)!!

                    val hereUrl: Uri? = result.data
                    val inputStream = this.contentResolver.openInputStream(hereUrl!!)
                    val byteArray = inputStream!!.readBytes().contentToString()


                    Timber.i(byteArray.toUtf8Bytes().toString())
                }
            }
       }
}
```

But as a result I receive such output at logcat:

```
[B@70da221
```

So, how to get such couples of numbers and letters?

### UPDATE

I have created such function:

```
fun byteToHex(num: ByteArray): ArrayList<String> {
        val stringArray = ArrayList<String>()
        for (i in num.indices){
            val hexDigits = CharArray(2)
            hexDigits[0] = Character.forDigit(i shl 4 and 0xF, 16)
            hexDigits[1] = Character.forDigit(i and 0xF, 16)
            stringArray.add(String(hexDigits))
        }


        return stringArray
    }
```

and receive such output:

```
00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0d, 0e, 0f, 00,
```

but as I see smth goes wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your byte array in `String` format then you have to use `Arrays` to convert `byteArray` to `String` like below.

```
Timber.i(Arrays.toString(byteArray))
```

For that, you have to convert each byte to Hax using the below function.

**Java**

```
public String byteToHex(byte num) {
    char[] hexDigits = new char[2];
    hexDigits[0] = Character.forDigit((num >> 4) & 0xF, 16);
    hexDigits[1] = Character.forDigit((num & 0xF), 16);
    return new String(hexDigits);
}
```

Comment: I get such output `1, -31, 10, -2, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0` but I need numbers with letters :(

Comment: `fun byteToHex(num:Byte):String {
        val hexDigits = CharArray(2)
        hexDigits[0] = Character.forDigit((num shr 4) and 0xF, 16)
        hexDigits[1] = Character.forDigit((num and 0xF), 16)
        return String(hexDigits)
    }`

this function has errors at `shr` and `and` words, as you can see I use kotlin at my app

Comment: just create one java constant file and put this function in java file and use it in your kotlin file.

Comment: how do you compare byte variable with integer one? maybe I have to convert this byte to int?

Comment: @Andrew : you have to just for loop with each byte which you get in your byte array with byteToHax function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212338/discussion-between-mehul-kabaria-and-andrew).